# Book recommendation for Jewish-Buddhist dialogue and Jewish reactions to Buddhist doctrines

Tags: product-recommendation, judaism

I'm looking for some book recommendations for how Jews view various Buddhist teachings and doctrines and engage in Jewish-Buddhist dialogues.

Maybe something similar to what I'm looking for is "Rabbi on the Ganges: A Jewish-Hindu Encounter" (this of course, is a Hindu-Jewish equivalent, written from a Jewish point of view).

Basically a book which analyzes Buddhist doctrines and makes parallels  with Jewish views.

Generally, I would like the book to be from a Jewish perspective/POV (not comparative religion, but a book recommendation about Jewish perspectives).

Comment: "...analyzes Buddhist doctrines and makes parallels with Jewish views" - How is this not comparative religion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the exact [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568713568) you are looking for is "Letters to a Buddhist Jew" by Rabbi Dr. Akiva Tatz and David Gottlieb.